# check ruby code for NoMethodError or NameError

Tags: ruby, checkstyle, code-inspection

Is there a way to check ruby code to prevent 'NoMethodError' or 'NameError'?

I tried some gems: rubocop, reek, roodi. Useful tools for ruby best practices but not for my need.

I use vim so a cli tool will be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: In ruby methods can be defined during the execution, so there is no way to tell whether given method will be defined at the time it is called. In some cases, the method is never defined, but it relies on method_missing to handle it. This is one of the many reasons why you should always write tests.

Comment: I saw that RubyMine can 'detect' this type of error 'on-the-fly' and they says the inspection feature is based on the tools I mentioned.
I saw the way of using method_missing to handle this exception but it needs to run the program.

Comment: this is what I am saying here - there is no way to tell without running the code. Best way to run the code is to have well written test suite with high code coverage.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but the `did_you_mean` gem is pretty nifty when handling such errors http://www.yukinishijima.net/2014/10/21/did-you-mean-experience-in-ruby.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I want :) : `ruby-lint`

https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-lint/

https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint

```
Analysis Classes:

  * argument_amount
  * pedantics
  * shadowing_variables
  * undefined_methods
  * undefined_variables
  * unused_variables
  * useless_equality_checks
```

I search for "ruby static code checker"

Thank you for your help